# Button press fired on angular form submit

Tags: angularjs

I have a form with an input text field as well as a button. I'd like to capture the user pressing enter in the text field - not to submit the form, but to trigger another action. The button has its own separate click handler that for some reason gets fired when I press enter in the text field.

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/T8zLq/1/

```
<form onsubmit="return false" ng-submit="mysubmit()" ng-controller="TestCtrl" ng-app="Test">
    <input type="text" />
    <button ng-click="test()">X</button>
</form>

var app=angular.module("Test", []);

app.controller("TestCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.test = function() {alert('lol');  };
    $scope.mysubmit = function() {alert('submit');};
}]);
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: So what do you want to happen? do you want test() to NOT fire but mysubmit() to fire when you press enter? Or do you want neither to fire?

Comment: Correct - test() should only fire when I press the button, not when the form is submitted

Answer (score 13, accepted):

set `type='button'` to your button

```
<form ng-submit="mysubmit()" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <input type="text" />
    <button ng-click="test()" type='button'>X</button>
</form>
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roine/zd3af/1)</kbd>

[More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms)

Comment: Ah, didn't realize default button type was 'submit'.

Comment: @beku8 The default value for button is *submit*, so every time you press enter it'll submit the form.